# fills with \tikzfillbetween

Tags: tikz-pgf

I have this code and I want to fill between A and B but I can't. I think \tikzfillbetween has a specially packaged one, but IDK.

```
‎\begin{minipage}{5.8cm}‎
‎\begin{figure}[H]‎
‎\begin{center}‎
‎\scalebox{.7}{‎
‎\begin{tikzpicture}[thick,simple/.style={fill=black,inner sep=.4mm,circle,color=black‎,  ‎minimum size=0mm}]‎
‎\draw[ very thick,->] (-.5,0)‎ -- ‎(8‎,0) node[right] {‎$‎X‎$‎};‎
‎\draw[very thick,->] (0,-.5)‎ -- ‎(0,5) node[above] {‎$‎Y‎$‎};‎‎

‎\draw[ very thick,dashed, ‎name path=A] (1.5,0)‎ -- ‎(1.5,4.3) node[right] {};
‎‎‎
‎\draw[ very thick,dashed, ‎name path=B] (6.5,0)‎ -- ‎(6.5,4) node[right] {};‎‎‎
‎
‎\node at(1.5,-.3){$a$};‎‎
‎\node at(6.5,-.3){$b$};‎
‎\node at(5,4){$f$};‎‎
‎\draw [very thick]  (1,3.5)‎ .. ‎controls (1.7‎,‎4.7)‎  .. ‎(2.5,4.5);‎‎
‎\draw [very thick]  (2.5,4.5)‎ .. ‎controls (5‎,2.5)‎  .. ‎(7,4.5);‎‎
‎
‎\tikzfillbetween[of=A and B]{line width=0pt,pattern=north east lines,};‎
‎\end{tikzpicture}‎ }
‎\end{center}‎
‎\end{figure}‎
‎\end{minipage}‎
‎\begin{minipage}{8cm}‎
‎\begin{flushleft}‎
‎$s=\int_{a}^{b}f(x)dx
‎$‎
‎\end{flushleft}‎
‎\end{minipage}‎‎
```

Comment: Welcome to the TeX.SE. community. What is the complete minimal working example?

Comment: @Sebastiano refers to https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-working-example-mwe-what-is-that.

Comment: @CampanIgnis Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 3):

You don't need `fillbetween`, at least if you know the curve or the coordinates of the points `a` and `b`. For example with an approximate (and smooth) curve you can get:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=2mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{patterns}

\tikzset
{% example function:
   declare function={f(\x)=0.1*(\x-4)^3-0.7*(\x-4)+4;}
}

\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}[thick]
    \draw[very thick,->] (-0.5,0) -- (8,0) node[right] {$X$};
    \draw[very thick,->] (0,-0.5) -- (0,5) node[above] {$Y$};
    \fill[pattern=north west lines] (1.5,0) -- (1.5,{f(1.5)}) -- plot [domain=1.5:6.5,samples=61] (\x,{f(\x)}) -- (6.5,0) -- cycle;
    \draw[very thick,dashed] (1.5,0) node[below] {\strut$a$} -- (1.5,{f(1.5)});
    \draw[very thick,dashed] (6.5,0) node[below] {\strut$b$} -- (6.5,{f(6.5)});
    \node at(5,4){$f$};
    \draw[very thick] plot[domain=1:7,samples=71] (\x,{f(\x)});
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

With almost the same code of Juan You can have this result (without the `pattern` library):

[image]

Simply change the line of pattern fill with this one:

```
\foreach \x in {1.50,1.52,...,6.50}
        \draw[gray!20] (\x,0)--(\x,{f(\x)});
```

Obviously You can also change the color as You want (I used `gray!20`).